# Gnome-shell fails to load on 12.10

Tags: gnome, fglrx

I'm usually the one answering questions, but in this I'm throughly stumped!

**My Setup:**

Ubuntu 12.10 (Dist upgrade form 12.04)
ATI M96 [Mobility Radeon HD 4650]

Upon the first installation of 12.10 I had all kinds of issues getting the Legacy ATI drivers to install (I guess the source for the drivers isn't kosher with kernel 3.5). So, I added the repository ppa:makson96/fglrx - which has a version of the ATI source patched to work with kernel 3.5. After installation of fglrx-legacy from that PPA, gnome-shell and all my graphics work fine... until today.

**The Problem**

I unsuspended my computer today and the screen was black (not off, the black from the gnome lock screen). I'd move my mouse/hit a key and the background would flash and then it'd go back to black.

Restarted via VT1

Logged into Gnome (gnome-shell) session, but no gnome-shell!

**Investigation:**

First, I went to VT1 and tried `export DISPLAY=:0;gnome-shell --replace`. It appeared to work fine, switch back to X and nothing. Went back to VT1 and saw this error message:

```
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Object 0x7fc748129c30 is not a subclass of (null), it's a xŌ
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Object 0x7fc748129c30 is not a subclass of (null), it's a xŌ"'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/tweener.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '218'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/tweener.js:218
wrapper()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:204
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:145
()@/usr/share/gjs-1.0/lang.js:239
init()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/tweener.js:49
init()@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/environment.js:96
@<main>:1
"'
Window manager warning: Log level 32: Execution of main.js threw exception: TypeError: Object 0x7fc748129c30 is not a subclass of (null), it's a xŌ
```

Note: Everywhere it says "it's a xŌ", xŌ is actually garbled and changes every time (I'm thinking memory corruption?)

This error is thrown by line 96 of /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/environment.js: `tweener.Init()`

Did a purge of fglrx-legacy, reboot, reinstall fglrx-legacy, reboot... same thing.

Did a ppa-purge of ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3, and reinstalled gnome-shell and ubuntu-desktop from the standard repositores... same thing.

I'm really at a loss here. I love gnome-shell and after using it for nearly a year now
gnome classic just seems so archaic.

**Additional Information**

Apt log from the day I first suspended my machine (these are upgrades from the gnome3-team/gnome3 ppa and ubuntu-wine/ppa ppa):

```
Start-Date: 2012-11-24  17:30:28
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.618'
Install: gkbd-capplet:amd64 (3.6.0-0ubuntu1), gnome-control-center-unity:amd64 (1.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.10.1)
Upgrade: nautilus:amd64 (3.6.2-0ubuntu0.1~quantal1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1), libgnome-control-center1:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu19, 3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1), wine1.5-i386:i386 (1.5.17-0ubuntu4, 1.5.18-0ubuntu1), wine1.5:amd64 (1.5.17-0ubuntu4, 1.5.18-0ubuntu1), gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu14, 3.6.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.10.1), gnome-control-center-data:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu19, 3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1), gnome-accessibility-themes:amd64 (3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1, 3.6.2-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1), gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1, 3.6.2-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1), wine1.5-amd64:amd64 (1.5.17-0ubuntu4, 1.5.18-0ubuntu1), nautilus-data:amd64 (3.6.2-0ubuntu0.1~quantal1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1), gnome-control-center:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu19, 3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1), libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (3.6.2-0ubuntu0.1~quantal1, 3.6.3-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1)
End-Date: 2012-11-24  17:31:32
```

fglrxinfo (driver appears to be working):

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11653 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Does anybody have any further ideas?

Comment: Looks like libgnome-control-center1 3.6.3-0ubuntu6~ubuntu12.10.1 from the Gnome3-team PPA was a backport. That could be a potential problem (though I'd assume it was tested prior to release).

Comment: Actually, looks like the majority of these updates are backports. However, it's kind of odd that the package manager didn't pick up these updates before - I've been using the PPA for a very long time, even installed it right after upgrading to 12.10. Yet, it appears that the official versions were still installed up until yesterday. However, downgrading back to the official repository versions did not fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm... I even reverted all changes from quantal-updates... nothing.

Comment: Are you using Gnome-Shell 3.6? And only 1 monitor or more? I'm asking because I have a similar setup with 3 monitors and cant get it to work at all with the fglrx drivers.